# Gacha problem - Expected value of random boxes when there's a reward for Nth fail

Tags: probability

[Problem]

A random box has the following attributes:
`1.5%` S rank reward(100 value), `13.5%` A rank reward(10 value), `85%` empty(0 value).

`E(V)` of this box would of course, be `2.85`.

**However**, here's the catch. **When the box comes up empty 9 times in succession, the next box is guaranteed to have a reward of A rank or more**. Therefore, after opening empty boxes for 9 times **in succession**, the next box will be guranteed to have `10%` S rank(100 value), or `90%` A rank(10 value).

I feel like this would be impossible to solve mathematically instead of programmatically.

[Question]

Is it possible to calculate the actual expected value of this box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the payoff of the box, and let $E$ be the event that the previous nine boxes were empty.
$$
\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[X|E]P(E)+\mathbb E[X|E^c]P(E^c)=(0.1\cdot 100+0.9\cdot 10)\cdot (0.85)^9+2.85\cdot(1-(0.85)^9)
$$

Comment: Thanks xD I can't believe I thought this was that complicated. At the end of the day, the only thing that matters is if the previous outcomes had been 9 times fail or not. I was trying to approach this by dividing all the possible combinations and adding them, which was a wrong way to solve. Thank you!